# Python: parallelize for loop and save results in dictionary passed by reference

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I would like to parallelize following function, where A and B are just some columns from my input data frame. I would like to provide the output dictionary as an input so it is filled within the function (pass by reference)

```
outdict = {}

inputdict1 = {'id1': 100, 'id2': 200, 'id3': 0}
inputdict2 = {'id1': ['cat'], 'id2': ['dog', 'rabbit'], 'id3': []}
inputdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'rabbit'],
                        'B': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']})

def processing(outdict, inputdict1, inputdict2, inputdf):
    for key, _ in tqdm(inputdict1.items()):
        outdict[key] = inputdf[inputdf.A.isin(inputdict2[key])].B.nunique()
        
processing(outdict, inputdict1, inputdict2, inputdf)

print(outdict)
```

> {'id1': 3, 'id2': 4, 'id3': 0}

After some research I have tried the following approach

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def processing(outdict, inputdict1, inputdict2, inputdf):
    for key, value in tqdm(inputdict1.items()):
        outdict[key] = inputdf[inputdf.A.isin(inputdict2[key])].B.nunique()

outdict = {}

pool = Pool()
pool.starmap(processing, zip(outdict, inputdict1, inputdict2, inputdf))

print(outdict)
```

> {}

Comment: I'm not expert in the subject, but I don't think it is possible for two different _processes_ to share a reference to the same dictionary. Two different threads can do that, but not two different processes.

Comment: P.S., Technically speaking, "pass \_by\_ reference" means something other than passing \_a\_ reference in to a function call. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088820/801894